# Javascript ES6 export const vs export let

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

Let's say I have a variable that I want to export. What's the difference between

```
export const a = 1;
```

vs

```
export let a = 1;
```

I understand the difference between `const` and `let`, but when you export them, what are the differences?

Comment: `export` keyword details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). Currently it is not supported natively by any of the web-browsers.

Answer (score 351, accepted):

In ES6, `import`s are live read-only views on exported-values. As a result, when you do `import a from "somemodule";`, you cannot assign to `a` no matter how you declare `a` in the module.

However, since imported variables are **live** views, they do change according to the "raw" exported variable in exports. Consider the following code (borrowed from the reference article below):

```
//------ lib.js ------
export let counter = 3;
export function incCounter() {
    counter++;
}

//------ main1.js ------
import { counter, incCounter } from './lib';

// The imported value `counter` is live
console.log(counter); // 3
incCounter();
console.log(counter); // 4

// The imported value can’t be changed
counter++; // TypeError
```

As you can see, the difference really lies in `lib.js`, not `main1.js`.

---

**To summarize:**

- You cannot assign to `import`-ed variables, no matter how you declare the corresponding variables in the module.
- The traditional `let`-vs-`const` semantics applies to the declared variable in the module.

  - If the variable is declared `const`, it cannot be reassigned or rebound in anywhere.
  - If the variable is declared `let`, it can only be reassigned in the module (but not the user). If it is changed, the `import`-ed variable changes accordingly.

Reference:
http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#leanpub-auto-in-es6-imports-are-live-read-only-views-on-exported-values

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74443888/why-doest-es6-default-exports-are-not-live

Answer (score 2):

I think that once you've imported it, the behaviour is the same (in the place your variable will be used outside source file).

The only difference would be if you try to reassign it before the end of this very file.