# Extending namespaced JS imports

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6

This is a general ES6 question, but I've encountered it in the context of React Native. The basic problem is that I want to override some components that I usually import from the 'react-native' module with my own components. My method for doing this looks like the following:

---

Instead of requiring components with `import { Text, View, etc } from 'react-native'`

require them like this: `import { Text, View, etc } from './ui_components'`

where `ui_components.js` looks something like:

`export * from 'react-native'`

---

The issue is, how do I add my own components to this export? Ideally I'd be able to add them in `ui_components.js` by doing something like this:

```
import * as RN from 'react-native'
RN.Text = myTextComponent
RN.View = myViewComponent
export * from RN
```

But this doesn't quite work. Any ideas?

Comment: RN object is supposed to be read only, you can't modify it.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import React Native's component and reexport it, with or without extensions from your side - it's up to you.

But remember - don't ever override React's internals (or any other's internals). Components are composable, yay!

For example, here, I am creating my custom `Text` component cause I want all texts in my app to be red by default. Also I want it to be configurable if I need different color for title/subtitle/whatever...

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text as NativeText } from 'react-native';

export default function Text({ style, ...props}) {
    return <NativeText style={[ { color: 'red' }, style]} {...props} />
}
```

Got an idea?

Good, now to folder structure...

```
ui_components
| - index.js
| - Text.js

// Text.js
// See example above...

// index.js
export { default as Text } from './Text';

// In your app
import { Text } from './ui_components';
```

Comment: This helps, thank you. I was hoping to make it so that I could import all my components from the same place, whether they were custom or not. But keeping them separate is probably better for code clarity.