# Cannot assign exported class instance in typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have an model store class whose instance would be exported like below:

```
export class CartStore {
    ...
}

export default new CartStore();
```

Later in my Network module class when parsing the response JSON from axios:

```
import cartStore from "./CartStore"

...

export async function addToCart(timeslotId: number, quantity: number) {
    return await axios.post(sprintf(Constants.ENDPOINT_ADD_TO_CART, {
        "timeslot_id": timeslotId
    }), { "quantity": quantity }, getConfig())
        .then(res => {
            let data = (res as AxiosResponse).data;
            if (data != null) {
                // **compilation error** below saying that "cannot assign to 'cartStore' because it is not a variable"
                cartStore = Deserialize(data, CartStore); // <-- 
                ...
            } else {
                console.warn("[NetworkManager]", `null response when addToCart with timeslot id: ${timeslotId}`);
            }
        })
        .catch(defaultErrorHandler);
}
```

I am using [`cerialize`](https://github.com/weichx/cerialize) lib for deserializing my `CartStore` through `Deserialize`.

Is it the class instance being exported `readonly` by default? How to fix the above error?

**UPDATE**

Related answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558929/510577

Comment: Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot!