# Change the value of imported variable in ES6

Tags: javascript, import, ecmascript-6

I'm using ES6 modules and am importing a variable from `moduleA` into `moduleB`:

```
//moduleA.js
let a = 5;
let b;

export { a, b };

//moduleB.js
import { a, b } from './moduleA'

a = 6;
b = 1;
```

But on change/assignment in `moduleB` I'm getting error such as:

> a = 6;
>
> ReferenceError: a is not defined

On the other hand I can `console.log(a)` in `moduleB`.

It seems it is not possible to assign to imported variables? Is this true or am I missing the way to do it? Why is this not possible?

Comment: In ES6, imports are live read-only views on exported-values. https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558929/2894798

Comment: @RenzoCC you should post an answer using that as a reference, as both questions are a bit different it's not a duplicate

Comment: What misses there is to note that if a or b (in my example) is an object you CAN mutate it from any module. What you cannot do apparently is reassign a and b variables. Am I correct?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

```
import { a, b } from './moduleA'
```

is similar to

```
const a = ...
const b = ...
```

in that you cannot assign the value afterward. It's not quite the same because the values *can* change, but they can only be changed from *inside* the module. So you could do

```
let a = 5;
function setA(value) {
  a = value;
}

export { a, setA };
```

with

```
import { a, setA } from "./moduleA";

setA(4);
console.log(a); // 4
```

From outside of a module you can *mutate* a value, just like you could with `const`, like if you're changing a property on an object, but you cannot make the variable point to an entirely different object.

Answer (score 35):

You can use an object instead of variables, like this the reference doesn't change :

```
//moduleA.js
let object = {
    a: 5,
};

export { object };

//moduleB.js
import { object } from './moduleA'

object.a = 6;
object.b = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm already using this approach. Or as other answers noted use a setter function residing in moduleA. I think it is confirmed that there is restriction in reassigning other modules' exports. Don't know why other answers got deleted though.