# can a exported variable be changed in the original file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

first.js

```
var a='this is first.js'

module.exports=a;
```

second.js

```
var a=require('./first');

console.log(a);
```

> output:this is first.js

if i change the content of 'a' in second.js will that reflect in first.js too? if not and if possible how to do it?

first.js

```
var a='this is first.js'

module.export=a;
```

second.js

```
var a=require('./first');

console.log(a);
```

Comment: Here is the answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168601/change-the-value-of-imported-variable-in-es6

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change the value of imported variable in ES6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168601/change-the-value-of-imported-variable-in-es6)

Comment: No. The reverse is possible with ES6 modules, but not in CommonJS modules. There you can only share and manipulate an exports object.

Comment: Btw it's `module.exports` not `module.export`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an object instead of string.

**first.js**

```
var a = {

    txt : 'this is first.js'
}

function too() {
    console.log(a.txt);
}
module.exports = { foo: a, too:too };
```

in the app.js , you can modify it and it will be reflected eveywhere

```
var a = require("./first");
a.foo.txt = 'hahaha';
console.log(a.foo.txt);
a.too();
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

No. Assigning to `a` in the second module only changes the local `var`iable, nothing else.

> how to do it?

Export an object, not a single value. Then you can modify its properties from everywhere.

```
// first.js
module.exports.a = 'this is first.js';
```

```
// second.js
var first = require('./first');
console.log(first.a);
first.a = 'this is something else';
```