# Node.js global variable error 'Uncaught TypeError: "object" is read-only'

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, mjs

I am trying to check if 'object' is saved in Local storage, and if it is then assign a global variable the object in a separate file, however, in the console it is saying `Uncaught TypeError: "object" is read-only` (local-storage already contains information)...

Here is my code and files

object.mjs

```js
export let object = createObject();
function createObject()
    return {
        'name': undefined,
        'age': 0,
        'score': 0,
    }
}
```

app.js

```js
import { object } from "./lib/object.mjs";
object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Object'));
```

Comment: You cannot reassign an imported symbol.

Comment: To complete Pointy comment : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48168601/change-the-value-of-imported-variable-in-es6

Comment: I managed to find a way around it, by checking the localStorage within the object.mjs file, does the job perfectly. But yeah, that is good to know what an imported symbol cannot be changed...