# How could I export a const which is the value of an variable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Showing the code is easier to explain what I'm looking if it is possible to do.

`validations.js` file

```
export const required = 'REQUIRED'
export const email = 'NEEDS_TO_BE_EMAIL'
```

`translations.js` file

```
import { required as requiredValidation, email as emailValidation } from './validations'

export const { [requiredValidation], [emailValidation] } = defineMessages({
    [requiredValidation]: {
        id: `validations.${requiredValidation}`,
        description: 'Mensagem de obrigatoriedade do campo',
       defaultMessage: '{field} é obrigatório'
    },
    [emailValidation]: {
        id: `validations.${emailValidation}`,
        description: 'Mensagem de formato de email do campo',
        defaultMessage: '{field} precisa ser do tipo e-mail'
    }
})
```

I would like to export consts which would be:

`REQUIRED` and `NEEDS_TO_BE_EMAIL`, is there anyway to do it?

Thanks for progress!

Comment: check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let#32558929

Comment: Whats not working with your code?

Comment: export const { [requiredValidation], [emailValidation] }

@JonasWilms It's not a valid way... You need to name a const, and I need the name of the const to be the value of those vars...

Comment: Ah, now I get the question. I guess thats impossible without a compilation step

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible as far as I know. But here is what you can do. You can export a single object with dynamically generated keys though:

```
let obj = {};

obj[fooLabel] = fooValue;

export default obj;
```