# Updating my imported variable's value in React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am refractoring an app I've build using React.js. I am exporting a variable from the global scope of `Spotify.js` and importing it in two other files `App.js` and `Button.js`.
After calling a function from `Spotify.js` that sotres a new value to the variable, It's new value is exported to 'Button.js' but stays an empty string in 'App.js'.

Your help would be appriciated :)

```
export let userAccessToken = '';
export const Spotify = {
  ...
  getUserAccessToken (){
    //stores a new string to userAccessToken.
    }
  }
```

```
  import {userAccessToken, Spotify} from '../../util/Spotify';

  export class App extends React.Component {
    //a conditional rendering happens depending on if(!userAccessToken)
  }
```

```
  import {userAccessToken, Spotify} from '../../util/Spotify'

  export class Button extends React.Component {

      componentDidMount() {

      if (!userAccessToken) {

        console.log(`Button's UAT before calling the fn: ${userAccessToken}`)
        Spotify.getUserAccessToken();
        console.log(`Button's UAT after calling the fn: ${userAccessToken}`);

      } 
    }

  ...

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you share data between react components.

**Use react context or pass props between components**

You could use [react context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) to share data or simply pass it as props (if the components are closely related in the component tree)

Comment: Hey Jørgen,

Thanks for your replay :)
I context and props are used to pass information in a downwards flow between react components but (what I failed to mention was..) I am looking for a way to pass information from a utility file `Spotify.js` to a react component `App.js`.
As I mentioned above this seems to work with a different componenet, `Button.js`.

Should I link my repo?

Comment: Thanks for your time and support :)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can recommend is to export the userAccessToken, something like this, but you can't change its value [outside the module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32558929/7644199)

```
export const Spotify = {
  ...
  getUserAccessToken (){
    //stores a new string to userAccessToken.
    }
  }
  ...
}

const accessToken = Spotify.getUserAccessToken();
export const userAccessToken = accessToken;
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and support :)

Answer (score 0):

If you got to read this question I solved it.
Turns out I should have called my method `Spotify.getUserAccessToken()` from `App.js` using the react lifecycle method `componentDidMount()`.
The export and import methods are like snapshots of the module and therefore when I exported the variable `userAccessToke` from `Spotify.js` before calling the my method I imported an empty string and it did not update in all files.

Thanks Jørgen and joseluismurillorios for your support and time spent answering :)