# React Native How to edit and update an array data

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

I am very new in React Native. I have been trying to edit a data to an existing array Data file. lets make it more clear. I have a datafile name testData.js. where the data looks like this

```
const TestRoomData=[
    {
        id:"001",
        date:"24-April-2020",
        diagnosis: "seasonal flue",
        result:"this is some details on the result",
        prescription:"tamiflu",
        key: "33325254",
    },
    {   
        id:"002",
        date:"22-April-2020",
        result:"this is some details on the result editable",
        diagnosis: "Arthritis",
        prescription:"tamiflu",
        key: "33325255",
    }
];
module.exports= TestRoomData;
```

So I am showing the data through a flatlist by simply importing the data. Is there any way I can make some change to this list of data through textInput? In my flatList it has a button which navigate to Edit Screen. and in Edit Screen there are few text input.I understand how to pass the data between screens and I am able to pass it as placeholder. All I want is to make change in TestRoomData .

Could you please elaborate the process of just editing the data in my scenario please?

I have a long way to go learning, a little help is much much appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the test data array at runtime, but you will not be able to persist those changes if you don't save them somewhere.

Just do:

```
// Change it to "let" as it is not a constant variable.
let objTestData = [
    {
        abc: 1,
        def: 2
    },
    {
        abc: 2,
        def: 3
    }
];


function addToTestData(obj) {
    objTestData.push(obj)
}

module.exports = {
    objTestData,
    addToTestData
}
```

Then, import the "addToTestData" method

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { addToTestData } from './testData.js'

class MyComponent extends Component {
     //...

     myMethod = (obj) => addToTestData(obj)

     //...
}
```

You can't directly modify the test data array because, in ES6, [imports are read-only live views of the exported values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let). Instead, you should modify the array by using an imported method that has access to it.

**NOTE** Please, take in to account that those changes will not persist after an application restart. If you want the data to persist, you should use some data storage solution as [AsyncStorage](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/react_native/react_native_asyncstorage.htm)