# Cant export classes/anything in typescript - unexpected token export

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Problem every time i use the word export in TS with  unexpected token export.

Using typescript. Files have ts extension. Editor: VSC. Installed nodejs, angular, typescript etc. following the udemy course ive bought (too bad they dont reply to questions there). I am huge beginner and would like, if possible, get very simple answer (i know only Python and some Java). Problem on two computers, 3 different OS (including VM with Ubuntu)

Before i start i want to say ive searched all the google and SO similar questions. Reading them was like reading Chineese, i got nothing and those commands didnt help. My problem is like this:

```
    console.log("hello world");
let x = 20;
```

The moment i run this everything is fine (i run this via vsc terminal, command ts-node). The moment i add export before the variable i get the error ive written in the title. This isnt problem with variables only. At first i wanted to export and import a class (as in the introduction to the course on udemy ive bought). Everything worked fine until exports.

I created angular ng app (just like project in Djnago for example) but never got to changing anything in the files - during the introduction i was making ts files in a dir named sandbox and running them using ts-node command. Everything worked fine until exports. Its not even problem with importing, attempt to export something is enough reason to give that error. Just like below:

```
console.log("hello world");
export let x = 20;
```

(i wrote that as i remember it (files are in my VM, cant copy them) but the syntax was correct. Or at least - the same as in my Udemy course. Other ppl had this problem as well (no one got the reply alas).

This is my first post on SO. I do use it only if i have to and I never even needed to create an account and ask about anything. But this time im totally lost. If someone can, please help me. Im doing everything as in tutorial and idk why its not working. Idk about different versions of JS, frameworks etc. I was just simply following instructions that should work but they don't. If necessary, i can write down exactly all that i did, how i got it installed or provide any other information. Just please help.

Btw: Angular 10.1.6, npm: 6.14.4, tsc: 4.0.3. Both windows and linux (ubuntu) gives the same errors. Editor:VSC. Installed Angular, node.js and everything yesterday (on ubuntu today, the only difference was sudo before npm install commands) so it should all be up to date (if its not, im very surprised).

EDIT:

Thank you for answer. Here is an export with the class. Dont work as well:

```
export class Cust extends Persona {
constructor(name:string, age:number, private advisor:string)
{
  super(name, age);  
}

welcome(): string {

    return `Hello from ${this.name}, advised by ${this.advisor}}`;
}
```

}

Everything just like in an Udemy course... :(

EDIT2:

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/core": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.1.5",
    "@angular/router": "~10.1.5",
    "rxjs": "~6.6.0",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1001.6",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.1.6",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.1.5",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~4.0.2"
  }
}
```

EDIT3:
tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es2015",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

PS.Those are files from my computer, i cant copy-paste files from my VM. But it doesnt work on both computers and VM as well. Here are configs from the device i was providing examples with.

angular:

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "test": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/test",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "test:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "test:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "test:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "tsconfig.app.json",
              "tsconfig.spec.json",
              "e2e/tsconfig.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        },
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "test:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "test:serve:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }},
  "defaultProject": "test"
}
```

> EDIT: Never in my life have i thought running simple export command in
> TS requires Phd in Computer Science....

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

This did not resolve the problem, @Konrad J. is not able to use `export const` or `export class` either and I am at a loss!

**Original Response:**

I won't get into the nitty-gritty since you're a beginner, but you cannot `export let`.  You can however `export const x = 20;`

If you want the details, check out:

- [Javascript ES6 export const vs export let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32558514/javascript-es6-export-const-vs-export-let)
- [ES6 In Depth: let and const](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/07/es6-in-depth-let-and-const/)

Comment: only export class also gives me an error. And on my course in a video guy did everything just the same and there was no problem to export a class or import it. I know it must be something like version-related, and other ppl had the same problem too (cant wait to write a review of this course since they dont reply to questions btw...). Anyways, thanks for links :)

Comment: For me the hardest part of getting started with any technology is the setup.  It's likely that one of your configuration files is wrong.  `class` was introduced into javascript within the past few years, so you might be having problems if something is expecting an older version and doesn't understand `class`.  You might want to play around in an online environment like [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/) or [CodeSandbox](https://https://codesandbox.io/) while you're still learning because they can take care of the setup and allow you to focus just on writing code.

Comment: Does `export const x = 20` work without error?  And does declaring a `class` work if you don't `export` it?

Comment: Thank you i will try with object, does it change anything? Learning frontend is the worst part of my programming experience btw. If you know anything about basics of setting up, configuration files etc. please feel free to give a link. Anyways, i will try to read about it. But as far as i know, everything should be up to date because ive installed it today/yesterday...

Comment: Ok.  You may have come across [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38296667/getting-unexpected-token-export) already and found it to be unreadable.  But when I said that `class` is a fairly new feature I forgot the keyword `export` is fairly new as well.  When you import, is it with the keyword `import` or `require`?  Does it work if you write `module.exports = class Cust {}`

Comment: the exporting file: export class Cust extends... |importing file: import {Cust} from './cust'; Thats all. Just like in the tutorial :( No require or module.exports = ...

Comment: Ok it is very strange to me that `import` works but `export` doesn't!  Unfortunately I don't think I can be of more help because I don't know what's going on either.  You should edit your post with the contents of each of your configuration files (they are plain text files in the main folder of your project, often ending in .json) and maybe someone will notice something wrong.  In the meantime I would try working on you code in one of the online environments that I linked until you can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks. Should i paste all these files in json format? They are very long... PS. Import also doesnt work i just noticed that even export doesnt work so i focused on this while writing the post. The way i see it - if the export word caused problem, it must  be responsible for whats wrong. But the importing file doesnt work as well...

Comment: Ignore `package-lock.json` if you have one, but otherwise yeah just copy and paste the whole file and above it say which file name it is.  There should be an angular config, a tsconfig, and a package.json.  Hopefully the answer is in there somewhere.  Unless there is some setting in VSCode that needs to be changed?

Comment: I copied files from my computer where the imports dont work (like const, class etc). On my VM they dont work as well (which is really weird that the same error repeats in different os, environments, devices etc).