# Why are JavaScript default exports not live?

Tags: javascript

Why is the default export not live like a named export is?

```js
//------ lib.js ------
export let counter = 0;
export function incCounter() {
  counter++;
}
export default counter;


//------ main1.js ------
import { counter, incCounter } from "./lib";
import $counter from "./lib";

console.log({ $counter, counter }); // {$counter: 0, counter: 0}
incCounter();
console.log({ $counter, counter }); // {$counter: 0, counter: 1}
```

That shows that the named `counter` export is live but the default export isn't. Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I've ever been able to determine, it's purely because that's the decision that was made by the people defining modules, because they wanted to allow exporting the result of arbitrary expressions. What follows `export default` is an *expression*, not a binding (unless it's a function declaration or `class` declaration). For instance, this is a valid default export:

```
export default 6 * 7;
```

So your `export default counter;` is *evaluating* the value of `counter` and then exporting that, not a live binding.

You can see this in the grammars at the [top of the modules section](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/ecmascript-language-scripts-and-modules.html#sec-exports) of the specification:

> `export default` *HoistableDeclaration[~Yield, +Await, +Default]*
>
> `export default` *ClassDeclaration[~Yield, +Await, +Default]*
>
> `export default` *[lookahead ∉ { function, async [no LineTerminator here] function, class }] AssignmentExpression[+In, ~Yield, +Await] ;*

The first two cover function declarations and `class` declarations; the third, which exports the result of an *AssignmentExpression*, is what your code is using.

It *could* have been defined differently, it just wasn't. *(Subjectively: Probably for a good reason, a **lot** of thought went into the design of modules.)*

I suspect the reason for wanting to be able to export the results of arbitrary expressions was primarily around using default export to export the result of an object literal:

```
export default {
    something: "some value",
    // ...
};
```

That's useful when using a module as a configuration file, for instance.

Comment: I think also a useful reason to export expressions is `export default myFn()` because this also allows you to decorate the exports easily `export default Object.freeze(something)` or `export default memoize(calculationFunction)`